# how Access can communicate to SQL without using ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

Access will be the front end but I don't want to use ODBC on everyone's PC. Do you have any suggestions on how Access can communicate to SQL without using ODBC?

Comment: Do you want to use a different library or no library at all?

Comment: can you please tell me both the method with different library or without library also ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use ODBC? What is your reasoning?

Comment: every new user doesn't have the ODBC installed into the system , so i am looking for different solution

Comment: Like any other software, you will need to write an installer that ensures all prerequisites are set up.